# Are synchronization and race condition only for shared-memory model?

Tags: concurrency, distributed-computing

Are synchronization and race condition concepts only for shared-memory model?

In distributed memory model, when the processes communicate by ways other than shared memory, do synchronization and race condition still apply?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Race conditions still happen in distributed systems.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_memory#Shared_memory_vs._distributed_memory_vs._distributed_shared_memory), "The advantage of distributed memory is that it excludes race conditions, [...]". I do **not** agree with this statement as it stands. Here's my reasoning why:

If you're not communicating between processes, this is a trivial problem in both models; simply don't touch each others resources.

If you don't have an asynchronous network, your performance is going to suffer by a lot, so pretty much all cpu's are using asynchronous networks internally and externally.

If you're communicating asynchronously in some way between the processes, be it shared memory, message passing or what have you, there are going to be systems where race conditions can happen.

Consider A sending "let x = 4" to B.
Concurrently, C sends "let x = 5" to B.

Does x equal `4` or `5` after both messages are processed?

Even though **you'll never have a race at the memory level**, i.e. threads overwriting messages of each other or similar horrible things that can happen with shared memory, **the application can still suffer from race conditions at a higher abstraction layer**.